# Website not sending "Allow-Access-Control-Origin" header but browser still displays page

Tags: cors

I was reading about CORS just to test my understanding I looked at Network tab when sending a request to `www.facebook.com` or `www.google.com`. I noticed that FB doesn't return any "Allow-Access-Control-Origin" but of course the website shows up in the browser just fine.
I was wondering what other mechanism is in place such that the header is not needed to show the page? Is there some other header that replaces it? Or something sent from my browser (Chrome)?

Edit:

I don't see the `cross-origin-resource-policy` either.

Here are the response headers:

```
Request URL: https://www.facebook.com/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: [2a03:2880:f1ff:83:face:b00c:0:25de]:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
alt-svc: h3-29=":443"; ma=3600,h3-27=":443"; ma=3600
cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
content-encoding: br
content-security-policy: default-src * data: blob: 'self';script-src *.facebook.com *.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.google-analytics.com *.virtualearth.net *.google.com 127.0.0.1:* *.spotilocal.com:* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' blob: data: 'self';style-src data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' *;connect-src *.facebook.com facebook.com *.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.spotilocal.com:* wss://*.facebook.com:* https://fb.scanandcleanlocal.com:* attachment.fbsbx.com ws://localhost:* blob: *.cdninstagram.com 'self' chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd chrome-extension://dliochdbjfkdbacpmhlcpmleaejidimm;block-all-mixed-content;upgrade-insecure-requests;
content-type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
date: Tue, 24 Nov 2020 03:42:52 GMT
expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
pragma: no-cache
set-cookie: fr=1B2sduhQhogDrYwiQ..BfvFG_.nK.AAA.0.0.BfvIE8.AWU8c0bvhA8; expires=Mon, 22-Feb-2021 03:42:51 GMT; Max-Age=7775999; path=/; domain=.facebook.com; secure; httponly; SameSite=None
status: 200
strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; preload
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-fb-debug: ndydAg/NW2/VbbduVxankoEol25sCwdsJws3NLF6nP25Sx0H6PMjCLAx6tTuGUjT/ctGISGqVNDYnRerzJkEqw==
x-frame-options: DENY
x-xss-protection: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

When visiting https://www.google.com, the first cross-origin request I see in the network tab is https://apis.google.com. Same scheme (https), port number (443) but different domain (apis), so cross-origin right? But I don't see an `origin` request header, and therefore no `allow-access-control-origin` response header. What I do see, in the **response** headers, is the `cross-origin-resource-policy` header, with a value of `cross-origin`. You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cross-Origin_Resource_Policy_(CORP)).

When the server sets a `cross-origin-resource-policy` response header to a value of `cross-origin`, requests from any origin (both same-site and cross-site) can read the resource. This is the same behavior as setting an `allow-access-control-origin: *` header, but no `origin` request header is needed.

Comment: Please see my edit above

Comment: That’s for the very first request right?

Comment: Yes for the first one. The next ones do have the header but wouldn’t they be stopped by the first one?

Comment: I think the thing you’re confused about is the CORS policy is not applied to the first request. Your browser is asking for a resource at www.facebook.com. It gets it- then the browser starts reading the document. If the document contains instructions to fetch more resources (images, scripts, fonts etc) that are NOT located at the same place the first document was served from, CORS applies.

Comment: Ah right. Thanks for the explanation.